# change order of listview dynamically in xamarin forms

Tags: xamarin.forms, xamarin.forms.listview

I am using xamarin forms for my project. Here is my code.

In xaml Page:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             xmlns:customControls="clr-namespace:App5.CustomControls;assembly=HorizontalListView"
                 xmlns:local="clr-namespace:App5"
             x:Class="App5.MainPage">
    <ContentPage.Content>
            <ListView HasUnevenRows="True" BackgroundColor="#f3f3f3" SeparatorVisibility="None" x:Name="lstdb"
                      WidthRequest="250" HorizontalOptions="Start">
                <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <ViewCell>
                                    <Frame Grid.Row="0" Style="{StaticResource FrmDashboard}" Margin="5" 
                                           WidthRequest="200" HorizontalOptions="Start">
                                      <StackLayout WidthRequest="250" HorizontalOptions="Start">
                                <Label Text="{Binding ImageName}" Style="{StaticResource LblDashboard}"></Label>
                                <Label Text="{Binding DashBoardName}" Style="{StaticResource LblDashboard}"></Label>
                                <Label Text="{Binding DashBoardNameSmall}" Style="{StaticResource LblDashboardSmall}"></Label>
                                      </StackLayout>
                                    </Frame>
                        </ViewCell>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </ListView.ItemTemplate>
            </ListView>
    </ContentPage.Content>
</ContentPage>
```

In cs page:

```
public MainPage()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            AddData();
        }

        private void AddData()
        {
            lst = new List<DashBoardItems>
            {
                new DashBoardItems {ImageName="Image1", DashBoardName="Notification Alert", DashBoardNameSmall="4 Alerts"  },
                new DashBoardItems {ImageName="Image2", DashBoardName="PPM WO LIST", DashBoardNameSmall="4 Items"  },
                new DashBoardItems {ImageName="Image3", DashBoardName="Breakdown / Emergency WO List", DashBoardNameSmall="5 Items"  },
                new DashBoardItems {ImageName="Image4", DashBoardName="Asset Information", DashBoardNameSmall="2 Informations"  },
                new DashBoardItems {ImageName="Image5", DashBoardName="Portering", DashBoardNameSmall="2 Porters"  },
                new DashBoardItems {ImageName="Image6", DashBoardName="Raise Breakdown", DashBoardNameSmall=""  },
                new DashBoardItems {ImageName="Image7", DashBoardName="Tracking Technician", DashBoardNameSmall=""  },
                new DashBoardItems {ImageName="Image8", DashBoardName="Request Portering", DashBoardNameSmall=""  },
            };
            lstdb.ItemsSource = lst.ToList();
        }
```

I am getting output like below:
[image]

The list counts changed dynamically.
But the order should be change based on count of list like below:
[image]

Comment: Are you talking about the order or the layout ?

Comment: It looks like you might be looking for a [FlowListView](https://github.com/daniel-luberda/DLToolkit.Forms.Controls/tree/master/FlowListView).